# How to find '-s' inside a vim search

Tags: vim

I use Vim to read man pages. But I'm having trouble searching for variables.  For example I use:

```
/\<-s\>
```

to search for '-s', but it doesn't find anything. Grrr. I see it in the file.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\<` matches the beginning of a word, and `-` normally isn't considered a word character.  Do `:set iskeyword?` to see what characters are considered word characters.

Try this:

```
:set iskeyword+=-
/\<-s\>
```

Should work then.  See `:h /\<` and `:h 'iskeyword'`.

Comment: Brian is the only man who should provide the answer to the emacs vs. vim debate.

Answer (score 2):

`/-s` works just fine for me.

Comment: The problem is I want it word-delimited. There are lots of -s strings there.

Comment: ":set hi" and "nnnnnnnnn..." are your friends. I mean seriously, how many "-s"s are you going to see? A hundred?

Comment: Though on second thought... It is nice to know *why* the regexp you posted didn't work. Thanks Brian.

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching for where the man page describes the function of -s? Use `^\s*-s\>` to search for beginning-of-line, any amount of whitespace, and then your flag.

Otherwise, if you don't want to change your `iskeyword`, then you could try different regex for your delimiter. You could use `\s-s\>`, although this won't find "-s" (in quotes).

See also `:help pattern-overview`